# Express - set up different routes for different subdomains

Tags: node.js, express, routes, subdomain

I have an app running that I would like to have different routing for different subdomains. This is what I have tried:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
  if(req.headers.host == 'sub.example.com') { //if it's a sub-domain
    app.use('/', sub_routes);
  }else{
    app.use('/', routes);
  }
  next();
});
```

but that doesn't seem to actually work. I get a 404 error. When I set `app.use('/', routes);` outside of that block, routes work, but then I can't set them based on subdomain. I'm guessing the problem is that I'm trying to define the routes inside an already set route, but I'm not sure how else to go about setting these routes conditionally. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used this but have you tried https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-subdomain

It looks like it covers your use case perfectly.

You could also just use a different node process per subdomain and performing routing in nginx or Apache  to the applicable process.

Comment: I've tried using this, but haven't been able to get it to work on localhost. I added the subdomains to my host file.

Comment: So in that instance, is the issue with resolving the host on your machine or the module?

Comment: On the machine. If I use this module, it works great in my production environment. On my machine, my host file entry looks like this `127.0.0.1 localhost subdomain.localhost`. But the module doesn't recognize `subdomain` as a subdomain.

Comment: I was able to make this work locally. Here's another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564961/how-to-set-up-local-subdomains-for-node-js-app) I asked that explains how I did it.