# How to set up local subdomains for Node.js app

Tags: node.js, express, localhost, subdomain

I am running an express app on node.js. The app uses the [express-subdomain module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-subdomain) to help handle routes for two different subdomains (sub1.example.com and sub2.example.com). I'm hosting the app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. In my production environment, everything works great. But on my local machine, I cannot get this to work. I tried adding the subdomains to my host file `127.0.0.1 localhost sub1.localhost sub2.localhost`. Although that allows me to prepend a subdomain to localhost, the module doesn't recognize this as a valid subdomain, and therefor searches for subdomain routes in my root routes.

In main.js:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport);
var sub1_routes = require('./routes/sub1')(passport);
var sub2_routes = require('./routes/sub2')(passport);

app.use(subdomain('sub1', sub1_routes));
app.use(subdomain('sub2', sub1_routes));
app.use('/', routes);
```

I need to be able to handle this locally. It takes to much time to push a small change to AWS test, iterate, etc.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm the author of the module :)

For each new subdomain you wish to test locally you must add into your /etc/hosts file. So for example:

localhost is:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

a new subdomain would be..

```
127.0.0.1       sub1.localhost
```

and another..

```
127.0.0.1       sub2.localhost
```

Check out what I have done in the [tests](https://github.com/bmullan91/express-subdomain/tree/master/test).

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work for me and your tests only seem to check for localhost (without subdomains) and `example.com`. I was able to fix my problem by adding `subdomain.example.com` to my hosts file and using that as my dev url.

Comment: Sorry the actual reason is because there is not top-level domain, e.g. .com or .co.uk. I have updated the README to describe this.

Comment: Some clarification for dummies like me:
You need to edit the hosts file to resolve whatever development URL you want to use to localhost IP `127.0.0.1`. (IE:
`127.0.0.1 my-dev-url.com`, `127.0.0.1 admin.my-dev-url.com`, `127.0.0.1 api.my-dev-url.com`). Any URL will work, even existing ones. **Crucially**, if you're using Docker, this must be done to the hosts file of your _host_ machine, not the docker environment. In my case, I was running docker for windows in windows 10 so I needed to edit the hosts file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Answer (score 15):

I had same exact problem and I found a simple solution. Instead of writing `sub1.localhost` try replacing `localhost` with `lvh.me` this is a domain that always resolves to localhost and now whenever you write `sub1.lvh.me` even though a port like `sub1.lvh.me:3000` it will still work.

Answer (score 2):

There is an awesome website, which someone hosted for all of us.

localtest.me

All requests will be routed to 127.0.0.1, including subdomains.
e.g `something.localtest.me:3000`
will resolve to `127.0.0.1:3000`

but, for example, in your Express app, if you do

```
 app.get('*', (req, res) => {
     console.log(req.subdomains); // [ something ]
 });
```

you'll get your subdomain

Answer (score 0):

### on Ubuntu

For creating subdomains for localhost you just need to follow 2 simple steps.

Open your terminal by pressing `CTRL + ALT + T` then run the following commands:

```
sudo vi hosts
sudo -i gedit /etc/hosts # to edit /etc/hosts file
```

Once you run 2nd command `/etc/hosts` file will open and now this is the  place where you need to define subdomains.

Example: `localhost` is:

```
127.0.0.1       //our localhost

define new subdomain:
127.0.0.1       example.localhost   # first
```

and another..

```
127.0.0.1       demo.localhost      #second
```

that's it. Hope this was helpful.