# How to run multiple nextJs project locally under the same subdomains?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, nginx, next.js

i have two project running locally the first one is running on port 3000 and the second one on port 3001, and the problem is that i cant share http-only cookie between localhost:3001 and localhost:3000, so how can persist http-only cookie between those project ?

Answer (score 0):

Next.js does not have a feature for this by default, so you will need to host a webserver. You can use [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) which will forward all requests to/from sub.example to/from localhost:xxxx.

Alternatively, you could host a Node.js server to do this fairly easily. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564961/how-to-set-up-local-subdomains-for-node-js-app) explains this process completely.